# Join different result map with mybatis

Tags: java, mybatis

I have an object that contains as attribute other two object, like this:

```
public class A {
  private B b;
  private C c;
  ....
}
```

B and C have already their result maps in separated file .xml with mybatis.

I have a join query that return A and I need to create a new result map (in mybatis) wich contains the resultMap of B and the resultMap of C, but i don't want to rewrite the previous resultMaps.

Is there a way to merge the two resultMaps ?

Answer (score 3):

I have an Example to create a `resultMap` which contains other `resultMaps`.

```
<resultMap id="articleMap" type="com.xxx.tinybbs.entity.Article">
    <id column="ID" jdbcType="INTEGER" property="ID" />
    <result column="title" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="title" />
    <result column="createTime" jdbcType="TIMESTAMP" property="createTime" />
    <result column="pid" jdbcType="INTEGER" property="pid" />
    <result column="authorId" jdbcType="INTEGER" property="authorId" />
    <result column="boardId" jdbcType="INTEGER" property="boardId" />
    <result column="sourceIp" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="sourceIp" />
    <association property="board" javaType="com.xxx.tinybbs.entity.Board" column="boardId" resultMap="com.xxx.tinybbs.dao.BoardMapper.BaseResultMap">
    </association>
</resultMap>

<select id="getFullArticleInfo" parameterType="int" resultMap="articleMap">
    select article.*, board.* from article left join board on article.boardId = board.id where article.id =#{id};
</select>
```

Note that, import other resultMap `resultMap="com.xxx.tinybbs.dao.BoardMapper.BaseResultMap"`, `com.xxx.tinybbs.dao.BoardMapper` is the `namespace` of other mapper.xml

Comment: I need to insert 2 resultMap in one like this:
    <resultMap id="articleMap" type="com.xxx.tinybbs.entity.Article">
        <A resultMap/>
        <B resultMap />
    </resultMap>

Comment: `<association property="second" javaType="com.xxx.tinybbs.entity.Second" column="boardId" resultMap="com.xxx.tinybbs.dao.SecondMapper.BaseResultMap">`, the same as the first resultMap

Comment: I did it in this way:

<resultMap type="it.xxxx.cuc.dto.FatturaIncasso" id="fatturaResultMapDinamica">
     <association property="fattura" javaType="Fattura" resultMap="fatturaResultMap" />
     <association property="incasso" javaType="Incasso"       resultMap="it.xxxx.cuc.repository.IncassoRepository.incassoResultMap" />
    </resultMap>

This returns the last row of the query and I need all. Can you help me?